# getting response from HTTP header

Tags: caching, vbscript, fetch

I am trying to fetch and display the **'last-modification'** of the file from my server using VBScript, It is successfully fetching the 'last-modified' details but the date and the time it fetched is wrong

```
Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Set environmentVars = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process")
tempFolder = environmentVars("TEMP")
strURL = "http://testme.decentsms.com/gwbasic.rar"
strMethod = "GET"
objWinHttp.Open strMethod, strURL, False
objWinHttp.Send
GetDataFromURL = objWinHttp.GetResponseHeader("Last-Modified")
MsgBox GetDataFromURL
```

it fetch the following modified details,

**Last-Modified: Mon 21 May 2012 20:06:51 GMT**

while the actual file details are,

**Tue 22 May 2012 1:06:51 GMT**

I don't know what is wrong here, ?
I'm not able to sort out the problem, is it because of the cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script got some things mixed up, it's simple in fact, see this example, replace server and share with your path.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("\\server\share\gwbasic.rar")
Wscript.Echo "Date created:       " & objFile.DateCreated
Wscript.Echo "Date last accessed: " & objFile.DateLastAccessed
Wscript.Echo "Date last modified: " & objFile.DateLastModified
Wscript.Echo "Drive:              " & objFile.Drive
Wscript.Echo "Name:               " & objFile.Name
Wscript.Echo "Parent folder:      " & objFile.ParentFolder
Wscript.Echo "Path:               " & objFile.Path
Wscript.Echo "Short name:         " & objFile.ShortName
Wscript.Echo "Short path:         " & objFile.ShortPath
Wscript.Echo "Size:               " & objFile.Size
Wscript.Echo "Type:               " & objFile.Type
```